# Pass custom parameters in Event Bridge schedule event to lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have a Lambda function which gets invoked at a fixed schedule from EventBridge events. Is there any way to pass custom parameters(like a json file) to the invoked lambda function via an event rule?

I tried passing a json string inside withEventPattern in the PutRule object, like this:

`{'detail': {"id" : ["unique_id"]}}` => this lead to this error:

`"Event pattern is not valid. Reason: Unrecognized match type instance-id\n at [Source: (String)\"{\"detail\":[{\"instance-id\":[\"d1983a77-dc0e-4724-953f-df283c1ad421\"]}]}\"`

I understand this is not the appropriate way of doing this, but I was trying my luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use scheduled-events to trigger a lambda function then you should be able to use InputTransformer to add whatever static data you want to have delivered to the lambda (see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html)

Answer (score 3):

When you create the EventBridge rule, you can specify JSON to pass for the event.  Under "Additional settings" you can configure the target input, and one option is JSON.  The following shows this in the console, and similar options are available if you create the rule via the APIs or CloudFormation:
[image]